# Fluctuation dissipation theorems in dynamic processes: a comparison

Tags: quantum-mechanics, open-quantum-systems

I do not understand what the first and the second fluctuation- dissipation theorems physically represent and what are the differences between the first and the second on the physical side. As a reference, I am reading Sauermann et al. "The quantum statistics of dynamic processes", but I think I need a key to interpretate them properly.